# how to use two commands exit code for test in if loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to test two command exist codes in if loop but without any extra pipes for them

right now, I can use single command, eg.

```
if cmp -s file1 file2
then
....
```

but how to add two tests? would such be ok:

```
if cmp -s file1 file2 && test -f file3
then
...
```

the following does not work for me:

```
if [ $(cmp -s file1 file2) -a $(test -f file3) ]
then
...
```

Comment: I would try first option `&&` the second one is more about output than return code.

Answer (score 3):

```
if cmp -s file1 file2 && test -f file3
then
...
```

as written, the "if" will fail if either of the two tests fails, and succeed if they both succeed, which should be what you want. If you will need the output of the second test, you shouldn't do this, because it will not be run if the first test fails. Otherwise this seems like a good strategy.